# Android KeyStore Delete keys on update?

Tags: android, encryption, keystore

I know it's bad habit to ask questions like this, but I couldn't find any information online. I'm using KeyStore to store my encryption key for user's password and password expire time. When I updated the application for our test group, my KeyStore seems like can't find the old key and fails to decryption the users password. My question is does KeyStore delete the old keys every time there is and update? If so, is there a workaround that won't lose my encryption key?
And I'm open to other encryption and storing the encryption key methods too. I'm using this because I thought it's most efficient and easy way to implement to my code.